# Using Express, how to pass a value to a .js file using sendFile?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to pass data received when someone accesses a page and pass a value from the URL to a JavaScript file and store it as a value for a variable in that file and then send the file back.

I've read that you can use templating engines to do this however I couldn't find one that allows you to do this with JS files (only could find HTML).

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
app.get('/initial/:public_key', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public_scripts.js', {
    publicKey: req.params.public_key
  });
});
```

If so what do I need to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution to this without a templating engine.

This could be improved I'm sure but it's functional.

```
app.get('/initial/:public_key', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public_scripts.js', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
        let modifiedContents = contents.replace('%%PUBLICKEY%%',`${req.params.public_key}`);
        res.send(modifiedContents);
    });
});
```

In the `public_scripts.js` file there is a variable like this:

`var publicKey = "%%PUBLICKEY%%";`